# HasChanges() is always false when rows are modified unless I call the form's BindingContext EndCurrentEdit() method

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, dataset

So I have a `DataSet`, that I populate.  For test purposes, this contains a single `DataTable`.  This is populated from a query that returns a SQL `TABLE` which has two columns, `ID` and `Name`.  This table has one record in it.

I have a single `TextBox`, that I bind in the following manner:

```
Dim dv As System.Data.DataView = myDataSet.Tables("MyTable").AsDataView()
dv.RowFilter = "ID=1"

Dim dabi As New Binding("Text", dv, "Name") 
txtInput.DataBindings.Add(dabi)
```

This all works great in the application!  The `TextBox` populates with the value from the `DataSet`, and the value stored in the `DataSet` is updated as I enter stuff into the `TextBox`.

So, I make a in the `TextBox`, and then I go to save it.

I call `myDataSet.HasChanges()`.  It returns `False`, even though I've made a change.  Research suggests that this is something to do with the row not believing editing is 'finished' yet, but I'm not certain on this, as I've not been able to find a good source of information on how this is all working.

I have also discovered that `HasChanges()` will return the correct value (`False` for no changes, `True` for changes) if I precede the call to `myDataSet.HasChanges()` with the following line:

`Me.BindingContext(myDataSet.Tables("MyTable")).EndCurrentEdit()`

This is a method being called for what appears to be some sort of global binding context.  I've not done anything with this, or called any 'Begin Edit' methods, etc (research suggests such things may be private and called implicitly).

My questions then:  What's going on here?  Why is that line necessary for `HasChanges()` to work?  Am I doing something wrong in my data-binding to necessitate this line?  Does that line have any potentially unforeseen side-effects?

**EDIT:** `HasChanges()` will correctly return true if new rows are *added* without the call to `EndCurrentEdit()`, the issue only arises with modifications to existing rows.

Comment: HasChanges can only work after you told your dataset that you are done editing this record. When editing in a DataGridView for example it would return false when changing fields as long as you keep on the same record. Once you move to another record it will return true. Since you are using an EditBox you cannot move to another record and have to tell it you are done by calling the EndEdit method. This mechanism is usefull to edit more than one field for the same record and change the whole record at once in stead of field by field

Comment: There does indeed appear to be an `EndEdit` method for a `DataRow`.  Is there any good reason to do this for each record, rather than calling simply calling `EndCurrentEdit` globally?  For clarity, I'd be dealing with quite a few different controls, each one dealing with a different record.  Saving is only done when the save button is hit.

Comment: I usally cal the global EndCurrentEdit() as first line of code in my Save button code. In other methods where I change a value in a datarow in code I call the datarow endedit() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [`EndCurrentEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingmanagerbase.endcurrentedit(v=vs.110).aspx) cause the changes which you made on an [`IEditableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) be saved to underlying data source.

Since the [`DataRowView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IEditableObject`, calling `EndCurrentEdit` of the currency manager cause [`EndEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.endedit(v=vs.110).aspx) of `DataRowView` be called and commits changes to the underlying DataRow and ends the editing session.

Also when you change the position using binding source or change the position by click on another row of grid, if fact you are changing the position of currency manager which case `EndCurrentEdit` be called.

So to commit changes, you should call `EndCurrentEdit` directly or indirectly.

Comment: Since you said *Research suggests that this is something to do with the row not believing editing is 'finished' yet, but I'm not certain on this, as I've not been able to find a good source of information on how this is all working.* I tried to share some official sources ad descriptions about why you should call `EndCurrentEdit`.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)